# Drop Down Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, oracle11g

I have Drop Down List and I want to populate it from db. But its not working. Not showing any records.
Here is the Drop down list.

```
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlsubject" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown-
      select">
```

In Code Behind I uses the following approach.

```
     string oradb = 
     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conADULocal"].ConnectionString;

   if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
       using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(oradb))
            {
                using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT ID, 
             NAME FROM QAT_Subject"))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;

                    ddlsubject.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    ddlsubject.DataTextField = "Name";
                    ddlsubject.DataValueField = "ID";
                    ddlsubject.DataBind();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            ddlsubject.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Subject--", 
     "0"));

     }
```

At the moment it is not showing any record in drop down list.

Comment: Code looks ok. Are u getting any error?

Comment: NO, I am not getting any error

Comment: have u tried debugging it? Is 'ExecuteReader' returning records from Table or not?

Comment: Any data return from executing the command?

Comment: Yes, actually their is no data in table. so how table returns records.Thanks everyone for help